# Testing for an array's elements inside another array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I've used help from previous posts to get so far, but I just can't get this to work. I want to test if ALL group2 array elements exist in the group1 array. At the moment I'm getting opposite results to what I want.  I've tried reversing the code in the 'compare arrays' jQuery section, but no luck. Example outcomes are given below in columns.  https://jsfiddle.net/v82pfx2w/.  Can anyone shed light on this?

```
group1:                      group1:                      group1:
 Luxembourg                   Greece                       Greece
 Netherlands                  Netherlands                  Netherlands
 Belgium                      Luxembourg                   Luxembourg
                              Belgium                      Belgium
group2
 Netherlands                 group2                       group2
 Greece                       Netherlands                  Luxembourg
 Luxembourg                   Luxembourg                   Belgium
 Belgium                      Belgium

NO MATCH                     YES MATCH                    YES MATCH




https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js


<div id="containerStore">
  <div class='AggregCountriesBNLUX'>
  <label>Netherlands</label>
  <label>Greece</label>
  <label>Luxembourg</label>
  <label>Belgium</label>
 </div>

 <div class='AggregCountriesWEur'>
  <label>Netherlands</label>
  <label>Luxembourg</label>
  <label>Belgium</label>
 </div>

 <div class='AggregCountriesWEur'>
  <label>Luxembourg</label>
  <label>Belgium</label>
 </div>
</div>




var group1 = [];
group1 = ['Luxembourg', 'Netherlands', 'Belgium']

$('#containerStore div[class^="AggregCountries"]').each(function(i, obj) {

  group2 = $(this).map(function() {
      return $.trim($(this).text());
    })
    .get();
  group2 = group2.join();


// compare arrays:
  var compareGroups = group1.every(function(val) {
    return group2.indexOf(val) >= 0;
  })
  alert(compareGroups);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
var hasAll = group2.every(function(val) { 
    return group1.indexOf(val) >= 0; 
});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v82pfx2w/2/):

In your fiddle, you were not getting each label's text to separate index of `group2`. I have added `find('label')` which will return a collection. Also, you were doing `group2 = group2.join();` which replaced the array with a string.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error 'group2.every is not a function'.

Comment: Ah, so cause was that I wasn't 'finding' the labels. Your help much appreciated!

Comment: @Silverburch yeah. It was creating an array of length one, with the texts of labels concatenated.